# PickerFragment in facebook sdk 4.4.0

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Is there an alternative method to search for places (PlacePickerFragment) since facebook sdk 4.4.0?
Why did they remove the PickerFragments?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like there's a newer version but once you click the link there's nothing there. May be plausible for a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.5/class/PlacePickerFragment/

Comment: 4.4 is the newest version. At the changelog, they wrote that they removed the Picker Fragments...i don't know why ^^. Here is the link for the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x
(Since 4.4.0 )